# localhost didn’t send any data.- ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: java

But to check, localhost isn't responding properly, it says "the page didn't send any data. I tried looking everywhere and changed all the possible settings I can.

restored chrome settings cleared cache, cleared history, changed port numbers,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.InetAddress.*;

public final class WebServer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        // Set port number
        int port = 0;
        
        // Establish the listening socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Port number is: "+serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        
        // Wait for and process HTTP service requests
        while (true) {
            // Wait for TCP connection
            Socket requestSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            
            // Create an object to handle the request
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(requestSocket);
            
            //request.run()
            
            // Create a new thread for the request
            Thread thread = new Thread(request);
            
            // Start the thread
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}

final class HttpRequest implements Runnable
{
    // Constants
    // Recognized HTTP methods
    final static class HTTP_METHOD
    {
        final static String GET = "GET";
        final static String HEAD = "HEAD";
        final static String POST = "POST";
    }
    
    final static String HTTPVERSION = "HTTP/1.1";
    final static String CRLF = "\r\n";
    Socket socket;
    
    // Constructor
    public HttpRequest(Socket socket) throws Exception
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
    
    // Implements the run() method of the Runnable interface
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            processRequest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
    // Process a HTTP request
    private void processRequest() throws Exception
    {
        // Get the input and output streams of the socket.
        InputStream ins = socket.getInputStream();
        DataOutputStream outs = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        
        // Set up input stream filters
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        
        
        // Get the request line of the HTTP request
        String requestLine = br.readLine();
        
        // Display the request line
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Request:");
        System.out.println(" " + requestLine);
        
        // Close streams and sockets
        outs.close();
        br.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    
    private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream fins,
    OutputStream outs) throws Exception
    {
        // Coopy buffer
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0;
        
        while ((bytes = fins.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outs.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
    }
    
    private static String contentType(String fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".htm") ||
                fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".html")) {
            return "text/html";
        } else if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")) {
            return "image/gif";
        } else if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
            return "image/jpeg";
        } else {
            return "application/octet-stream";
        }
    }
}
```

please help me as soon as possible.I  need  help in this code.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

Posted code has a method `sendBytes` to apparently send data back, but it is **not** being called - no data is being sent back - the message is correct.

For each connection (attempt), the code is reading just one sent line, printing that to standard output and closing the connection. If I am not wrong, the browser is expecting a reply (positive or negative/error), but since the connection was closed without any reply, the browser must be showing the message that nothing was sent back.